# How to follow the lower max-width in css

Tags: html, css

So I'm not really good at css since I'm working more on the backend, I have two `max-device-width` where if the max is equal or less than to the value it will follow what style implemented but, I have this in css:

```
@media (max-device-width: 700px){
  .main-news .mn-img img {
    height: 15vh;
  }
}

@media (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  .main-news .mn-img img {
    height: 25vh;
  }
}
```

my problem is that when the device is already below `700px` its still follow the `1024px` style not on what i put on the `700px`. How can I do this? that when it is now below on the `700px` it will follow the `700px` style not the `1024px` style in css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media queries to specify a range, eg: `@media (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 80em) {...` and you can combine them as you wish. So use min-width and max-with to specify ranges.

Look here for a complete primer on media queries: https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

For 1024px, you need to do both min and max, so that it falls in a range. For example:

```
    @media (min-device-width: 701px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
      .main-news .mn-img img {
        height: 25vh;
      }
    }
```

Note that you can't have the specified width overlap with one another. If you want to set a small screen with 700px max-width, then the min-width for a medium screen should start at 701px.